# how to model a many-to-many relationship, associated with a has-many relationship rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following scenario:

Students belongs_to and has many courses,
courses has_many lessons
lessons belongs_to course

This is my current model:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :studentcourses
  has_many  :courses, :through => :studentcourses
end

class StudentCourse < ActiveRecord::Base //join table
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :student
end


class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :studentcourses
  has_many  :students, :through => :studentcourses
  has_many  :lessons
end

class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
end
```

Therefore students get assigned to 1 or many Courses, and Courses have many lessons.
How can I model it so that I can retrieve all lessons of all the courses of a student and all the students that belong to lesson?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use native `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship and specify than `Student` has many `Lessons` **through** `Courses`:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :courses
  has_many :lessons, through: :courses
end

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :students
  has_many :lessons
end

class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
end
```

And this is a migration for HABTM relationship:

```
class CreateStudentsCourses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  create_table :students_courses, id: false do |t|
    t.belongs_to :student, index: true
    t.belongs_to :course, index: true
  end
end
```

This way you can get all student's lessons `@some_student.lessons`, but, unfortunately, you can't get `@some_lesson.students`, because there's no `belongs_to :through` association, but you can delegate `students` method:

```
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  delegate :students, to: :course
end
```

This way, calling `@lesson.students`, method `students` will be called on an associated `Course`, which has this method defined.